# export image from lotus domino database

Tags: database, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm a beginner with Lotus so I really need help about it.
my company gave me a database in lotus. This database include around 18,000 images which I must import in a new DB developed in MySQL.
When I tried to open it with notes designer/notes the fallowing message is showed: 
`You have insufficient access to perform this operation`, I think there is a password that I 
do not know.
for privacy reasons I can not post nothing about the db, sorry.
So, how can I export all images as easy way as possible?

Comment: This question should be reopened. The OP is trying to use a development tool called Domino Designer, but he is being blocked by the security settings on the Notes database that he is trying to work on. This is a common situation for Notes developers, and although these security settings are normally considered an admin issue, understanding these settings is mandatory knowledge for all Notes developers -- especially when those settings interfere with the developers' own ability to use the required tools! That makes this question on topic.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to ensure you have sufficient access to the database. This means following:

- If database resides on a server, ensure you are allowed to access the server and have Reader access to the database (you may need higher rights, see below for details);
- If database resides on your workstation, you must ensure it's not locally encrypted by someone else or doesn't have Enforce ACL enabled;

With above in mind, exporting images from DB may require different approach depending on their location:

- Are they stored as design elements (Image Resource), then all you have to do is to open the database in Domino Designer, go to Image Resources, select desired image resource and perform Resource -> Export;
- Are they stored in documents, then this becomes a more complex task. You may use LotusScript or Java to iterate and process all documents containing images. For this, you would `NotesRichTextItem` class to retrieve `NotesEmbedded` object from each document. Alternative way would be to convert all rich-text field in document to MIME format using `Call notesDocument.ConvertToMIME( conversionType, options)` and process it after with `NotesMIMEEntity` class;

To access design of a database located on a Domino server you will need Designer rights.

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Dear, i will try it!, thank you very much for you kindly attention. regarding the access, i think i do not have the right because when i open the db with designer, the message "You have insufficient access to perform this operation" is shown. :-(